# How do I set specific index in two dimension arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> column = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    column.add(0);
}
for(int j=0; j < 12 ; j++) {
    row.add(column);
}
```

which it gave me

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

what I want is to replace a specific index in the arrayList. let's say 2nd arrayList of 3rd index with a 9.

```
row.get(2).set(3, 9);
```

but above replaces entire column with 9 instead. how should I set the arrayList to be specific without affecting other rows.

Comment: You add *the same* column 12 times.

Comment: yes for each row. it would be 12x12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently add the same exact column 12 times, but you should add 12 different ones, all shaped in the same way initially:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

for(int j=0; j < 12 ; j++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> column = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        column.add(0);
    }
    row.add(column);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you add the same instance of `ArrayList` as many times as you have columns, you need to create a copy first as next otherwise indeed all your columns will be affected by a modification:

```
for(int j=0; j < 12 ; j++) {
    row.add(new ArrayList<>(column));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't replace all the values, it only replaces the one value. Your problem is that all 12 elements of the `row` list is referencing the *same* column list.

You need to create a *new* column list for each row.

Also, indexes are zero-based, so to set the 2nd arrayList of 3rd index, you need to specify indexes 1 and 2, not 2 and 3.

If you know the exact size of the matrix, you should use regular arrays, not `ArrayList`.